# can i send parameters to another web page without php if current web page is not closed?

Tags: html

can i get all this information without any php code or script on an other web form?can i get all this information without any php code or script on an other web form?can i get all this information without any php code or script on an other web form?can i get all this information without any php code or script on an other web form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My Web From</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <a name="top">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <h3>Basic Infromation</h3>
                    </legend>
                    <li> Image
                        <input type="image" name="image">

                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                        <input type="button" name="btnUploadImage">

                    </li>
                    <br> First Name:
                    <input type "text" name="firstName" size="30" maxlength="25">

                    <span>
                        Last Name:
                        <input type "text" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="25">
                    </span>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                        <br>CNIC:
                        <input type="number" name="cnic" size="30" maxlength="25">
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li> Date Of Birth:
                        <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" size="30" maxlength="25">
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li> Email:
                        <input type="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="25">
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>Address:
                        <textarea rows=”10” cols=”40” name=”address”>  </textarea>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <br> Gender:
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male |
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female |
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
                    <li></li>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </fieldset>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <a href="#top">Back to top</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question is not very clear.

I assume that you want the input data of the form above to be displayed in another form on a different page, when the submit button is clicked.

If so, yes, you can get this information there using JavaScript.

What you would have to do to get there:

- Send form data via URL parameters (so something like `targetpage.html/?lastname=John&cnic=4545`and so on
- On the target page you'd have to implement JavaScript which gets those URL parameters (probably call them by name and store them in a variable to use them)
- Use the single parameters to populate the input of your form on this page or do whatever you want with it.

This has of course downsides. E.g. JavaScript could be disabled or manipulated, so you should be careful.